# Joomla insert article in helloworld component

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, joomla-3.5, custom-component

I would like to insert an article inside my component, does someone have an example on how to do that?
I created Helloworld component , I need to show items of articles in site component , 
**How to write code in model ,view, controller to show items?**
**Thank you**

Comment: Have you read through the Joomla documentation?

Comment: Yes but i need more documentaion!

Comment: Your question is too broad. Have a look at other components that ship with Joomla, especially com_content, try to write some code on your own and come back if you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad for any detailed response and we don't know where to start with an answer. But I will take a stab in the dark (despite it possibly leading to a Joomla horror movie...).

If you already have a MVC component going and want to pull data from other tables you should read up on database access in Joomla. 
https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

You are probably looking for data from these tables: 
jos_sections
jos_categories
jos_content

I hope that helps, however I would like to suggest that you investigate a component creator tool to assist you in understanding Joomla MVC layout. I use Component Creator (https://www.component-creator.com/en/), but there are lots out there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470272/component-builder-for-joomla

And if you have read the Joomla docs and still need more assistance you might try a Joomla book from Packt (https://www.packtpub.com/all?search=joomla).  I can recommend "Learning Joomla! 3 Extension Development-Third Edition". It has step by step directions for creating simple plugins and modules, as well as more complex components that are data driven.

HTH